# append columns of a data frame to a different data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, append, dataframe

Given these two pandas data frames:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a','b','c','d'], 'c':['x','y','y','x']})

  c1 c2
0  a  x
1  b  y
2  c  y
3  d  x

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['d','c','a','b'], 'val1':[12,31,14,34], 'val2':[0,0,1,1]})

  c1  val1  val2
0  d    12     4
1  c    31     3
2  a    14     1
3  b    34     2
```

I'd like to append the columns `val1` and `val2` of `df2` to the data frame `df1`, taking into account the elements in `c1`. The updated `df1` would then look like:

```
>>> df1

  c1 c2 val1  val2
0  a  x  14     1
1  b  y  34     2
2  c  y  31     3
3  d  x  12     4
```

I thought of using a combination of set_index and update:
`df1.set_index('c1').update(df2.set_index('c1'))`, but it didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pd.merge`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a','b','c','d'], 'c2':['x','y','y','x']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['d','c','a','b'], 'val1':[12,31,14,34], 'val2':[4,3,1,2]})

df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['c1'])
print(df1)
```

yields

```
  c1 c2  val1  val2
0  a  x    14     1
1  b  y    34     2
2  c  y    31     3
3  d  x    12     4
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great! How would you solve the problem if there were more columns in df2 (eg, val1, val2 and val3) but was only interested in val1 and val2? I tried pd.merge(df1, df2.loc[:,['val1','val2']], on=['c1']) but got an error.

Comment: Replace `df2` with `df2[['val1', 'val2', 'c1']]`.

Comment: You mean: pd.merge(df1, df2[['val1','val2']], on=['c1']), right? It's still giving me the same error: KeyError: u'no item named c1'.

Comment: @HappyPy :) : You need to include the `c1` column in `df2` -- otherwise `pd.merge` will not know on what shared column to merge. See my (edited) comment above.